# File not found while trying to compile Telegram source code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telegram

I am trying to build an app like Telegram.I downloaded their source code (https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) (for Android).

My main problem is that,when I try to compile the code and export it to my mobile phone,using Android Studio I recive this error:

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':TMessagesProj:packageDebug'.

> File 'C:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\Telegram\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\config\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

Obviously a file is missing,but which,and how can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

P.S. Can you please provide me with a link to the source code of an app similar like this one,or similar to whatsapp?

Answer (score 7):

Change Telegram/TMessagesProj/build.gradle and remove or comment signing option in gradle config, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.5.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
/**
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("config/debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("config/release.keystore")
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
*/
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
           // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        foss {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
           // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    sourceSets.debug {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.release {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/release/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    sourceSets.foss {
        manifest.srcFile 'config/foss/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 572
        versionName "3.0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!That was the problem

Comment: BTW do you know a method on how can I stop reciving sms from Telegram,and how to bypass the code verification process?